# Displaying the contents of an array (of strings) in JOptionPane

Tags: java, arrays, string, swing

I have here three classes that asks for input and should display an array of strings in a dialog box.

Class 1:

```
public class Card {

  public int rank;
  public int suit;
  public String rankName;
  public String suitName;
  public String cardName;

  public Card () {
    rank = 0;
    suit = 0;
    rankName = "";
    suitName = "";
    cardName = "";
  }

  public int getRank() {
    return rank;
  } 
  public void setRank(int rank) {
    this.rank = rank;
  }
  public int getSuit() {
    return suit;
  }
  public void setSuit(int suit) {
    this.suit = suit;
  }
  public String getRankName() {
    return rankName;
  }
  public void setRankName(String rankName) {
    this.rankName = rankName;
  }
  public String getSuitName() {
    return suitName;
  }
  public void setSuitName(String suitName) {
    this.suitName = suitName;
  }
  public String getCardName() {
    return cardName;
  }
  public void setCardName(String cardName) {
    this.cardName = cardName;
  }
}
```

Class 2 - this is the class where I should output the strings I have stored in an array. I think I'm on the right track doing generics part but I'm not fond to that though. Please guide me in printing all those.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Deck {

    public void assignIntegerValues(Card card) {
        //Card card = new Card();
        String[] suitNameArray = {"Clubs", "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds"};
        String[] rankNameArray = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
        List<Card> cardName = new ArrayList();

        card.setSuitName  (suitNameArray[card.getSuit()-1]);
        card.setRankName (rankNameArray[card.getRank()-1]);
        card.setCardName (card.getSuitName() + "-" + card.getRankName());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, card.cardName);
    }

    public void displayAll (Card card) {
        for (int i=0; i<card.cardName.length(); i++) {
            String print = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, card.cardName[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Class 3:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DisplayDeck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Card card = new Card();
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        int answer;
        String again;

        do {
            String suitString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Suit: ");
            card.setSuit (Integer.parseInt(suitString));

            String rankString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Rank: ");
            card.setRank (Integer.parseInt(rankString)); 

            deck.assignIntegerValues(card);
            String answerString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Try again? (1/0) ");
            answer = Integer.parseInt(answerString);
        } while (answer == 1);

        deck.displayAll(card);

    }
}
```

I'm trying to display the cardNames input by the user.

Comment: What are you trying to display?

Comment: Hello sir. I'm trying to display the `cardNames` input by the user.

Comment: See also [`Card`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).

Comment: @ConorSherman, I added `List<Card> cardName = new ArrayList<Card>)()` and I think it has something to do with `cardName.add(somethingHere)`, I just don't know the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach hinges on `Deck` having a collection to which each new `Card` is added:

```
class Deck {
    private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    ...
}
```

Were `Card` to override `toString()`,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return cardName;
}
```

then `displayAll()` becomes very simple:

```
public void displayAll() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        new JScrollPane(new JList(cards.toArray())));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Does the `public String toString` belong to class `Card`? When I run the program, the `JOptionPane` displays nothing.

Comment: Yes, I chose to override `toString()` in `Card`. To be honest, mine initially displayed nothing also. I had neglected to `add()` each `new Card()` to the `List<Card> cards`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I get it. I don't know which `add` you're referring to? Like this add `cards.add((Card) cards);`? I'm so sorry, I'm new in Java. But thank you!

Comment: Yes, `Card card = new Card(); cards.add(card)`, note the singular; if you use the generic declaration above, you shouldn't have to cast the `Card` to `add()` it.

Comment: Thanks! Should I place those inside `assignIntegerValues`? Since Eclipse says `Duplicate local variable card`, I changed the two occurrences of card into `card1` but still, it's not working. Even if I put it inside `displayAll`. I'm so sorry and thank you.

Comment: I did it in the `Deck` constructor, but doing it in `assignIntegerValues()` is a reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void displayAll (Card[] cards) {
    String output = "";
    for (int i=0; i<cards.length(); i++) {
        output += cards[i].getCardName() + "\n";
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
}
```

You need an array passed into displayAll otherwise you just have one card.

Then you build the output string before you ever actually create the JOptionPane.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much! If I'm going to call `displayAll` in another `DisplayDeck` class, what should be the argument? Thanks

Comment: An array of cards.

    Card[] cards = new Card[**Size Here**];
    cards[0] = new Card();
    ...